# How to make a curve mesh created in geometric nodes dependent on tilt

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I create multiple connected wires in one curve using geometry nodes. And I'm having a problem with how the geometry reacts to changing the shape of the curve. In the example, the geometry can be rotated independently of the curve shape using a tilt controller. But in my case it doesn't work. The geometry doesn't change at all. Instead, the geometry rotates as the shape of the curve itself changes.

[image: Example]
[image: Normal Position]

[image: Wrong position]

Briefly about how nodes work. For the main curve, 2 more curves have been created. One curve is used as the cross-sectional shape of the wire. The second curve is used to form a line along which the wire copies will be distributed.
[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Minimum` as the curve Twist Method, in which the base twist depends on the structure of the curve.

[image: Minimum twist behaviour]

---

Use`Z-Up` as the curve Twist Method, then adjust the tilt of all points. Now new points won't affect other parts of the curve.

[image: Twist Method ui option]
[image: z-up twist behaviour]